# Find total price given the quantity for each month and the rate for each month

Tags: google-sheets, formula

**Question:** What is the best formula to add quantity multiplied by different rates based on dates?

**Example:**

- Rate 1:  1/1/2017 - 4/30/2017   $5
- Rate 2:  5/1/2017 - 6/30/2017   $6
- Rate 3:  7/1/2017 - 12/31/2017  $7

**Apples per month**

- Jan: 10
- Feb: 30
- Mar: 10
- Apr: 50
- May: 40
- Jun: 70
- Jul: 80
- Aug: 40
- Sep: 20
- Oct: 10
- Nov: 40
- Dec: 100

The date is 5/9/2017. The formula would find that the date starts with Rate 2 and ends with Rate 3.

So, the calculation would be:
 `((40+70)*$6) +((80+40+20+10+40+100) *$7 )) = $2,690.00`

What is the best formula to calculate this way? Use `SUMPRODUCT`? I am baffled...

Answer (score 1):

Format a lookup table for rates, in which the first column is the date on which each rate goes into effect:

```
+----------+---+
| 1/1/2017 | 5 |
| 5/1/2017 | 6 |
| 7/1/2017 | 7 |
+----------+---+
```

Let's say the above is A1:B3. Now you can lookup the rate for any date (say a date is in C9) with

```
=vlookup(C9, A1:B3, 2, True)
```

Here `vlookup` searches for the date in the first column and returns the value from the second column for the nearest match that is less than or equal to the search key.

Then you can use sumproduct like this:

```
=sumproduct(D9:D15, arrayformula(vlookup(C9:C15, A1:B3, 2, True))
```

Here the rate is looked up for each date in the range C9:C15 (so those should be the first day of each month).

Finally, you want to do all of this, given a date like 5/9/2017. Suppose this date is in E1. Let's make 1 there. Say, in F1:

```
=date(2017, month(E1), 1)
```

Then filter the array of dates/amounts by the condition that the date is at least F1: `filter(C:C, C >= F1)`. The final result will be like

```
=sumproduct(filter(D:D, C:C >= F1), arrayformula(vlookup(filter(C:C, C >= F1), A1:B3, 2, True))
```

Comment: Thank you, Crazy Ivan. 

My fault for not being more clear. I think if I share a draft of the workbook, you will know what I mean: 
https://docs.google.com/a/convorelay.com/spreadsheets/d/1IGA9DsaoKcrSyYzp0Rk4G7Ue-2pa0cKUN1ukwChGBz8/edit?usp=sharing
The highlighted cells is where the formula should sit in.

Comment: Can you provide access? The sheet is protected.

Comment: Ah my bad - Here you go @Chef1075, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IGA9DsaoKcrSyYzp0Rk4G7Ue-2pa0cKUN1ukwChGBz8/edit?usp=sharing